# What happens to 'remaining' code execution on component re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React.js, let's say I have a parent component, which has a list in state:

```
myList: [1, 2, 3]
```

I do a .map() on `myList`, and render a new component for each item in the list. So my parent app now has child components.

Let's say that inside this child component, I run a method `myMethod`, and somewhere in the middle of this method I update the parent component's `myList` state variable.

This will trigger a re-render of the child components (including the current component) (correct?), which is executing `myMethod`, but has not yet finished executing all the lines of this method.

Main question:

What will happen to any remaining lines of code, inside `myMethod` method, that come after the line which causes the method's component to re-render?

(Will they still be executed, or will execution abort? Something more nuanced than that?)

Comment: Why would they abort? Also are you running into a specific problem, or is this just a general question ?

Comment: shouldnt it be an infinite loop? children update the state of parent, parent re-renders its children again

Comment: I imagine that any remaining code will be aborted, since the component will re-render. But I don't know how React works on that level, so I don't know, and that's why I ask. I am having a specific situation where I want to first update some parent component's state, triggering a re-render of the child while the child still needs to execute some code, including an axios request to a backend.

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous so it does not update your parent component state immediately. So, remaining code inside the method `myMethod` will not be aborted. All the remaining code is executed and only after that parent component state is updated and this will trigger a re-render. And also if you want, then you can update the child component state (after your axios request  to backend was resolved) inside same `myMethod` method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous so it does not update your parent component state immediately. So, remaining code inside the method `myMethod` will not be aborted. All the remaining code is executed and only after that parent component state is updated and this will trigger a re-render. And also if you want, then you can update the child component state (after your axios request to backend was resolved) inside same `myMethod` method.

eg:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    list: [1, 2, 3]
  };

  parentHandler = value => {
    this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, value] }, () =>
      console.log("parent component state updated")
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.list.map(item => (
          <Child key={item} item={item} parentHandler={this.parentHandler} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  state = {
    id: 24
  };

  fakePromsise = () => {
    const newId = getRandomInt(24, 60);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(newId), 5000);
    });
  };

  childHandler = listItem => {
    let newItem = listItem + getRandomInt(10, 1000);
    // handling parent state
    this.props.parentHandler(newItem);
    // handling fake promise
    // and when the promise resolves
    // update the component state
    this.fakePromsise().then(data =>
      this.setState(
        {
          id: data
        },
        () => console.log("child component state updated")
      )
    );
    // after the loop completes
    // parent state is updated
    for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      console.log("i", i);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 onClick={() => this.childHandler(this.props.item)}>
          {this.props.item} click me!!!
        </h1>
        <p>Id: {this.state.id}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> you can use the example and see the console result. Just click the `h1` tag. After which new `Child` component is added and the clicked `Child` component `id` is changed.